# Showing that set of all Hahn-Banach extensions of a functional is closed and has empty interior but need not be compact.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $Y$ be a subspace of a  normed linear space $X$ and $g\in Y'$. How do we show that the set of all Hahn-Banach extensions of $g$ to $X$ is a non-empty, convex, closed and bounded subset of $X'$ with empty interior but need not be compact.

1. The non-emptiness is just the Hahn-Banach theorem.
2. The boundedness follows from that all the extension has same norm as of $g$.
3. I can show that it is convex.

I am stuck with how to show it is closed, empty interior and need not be compact.

Comment: The empty interior part should also follow from the fact that the extensions have exactly the same norm as $g$.

Comment: Closed: $\|G_n-G\|\to 0$ implies $\|G_n\| \to \|G\|$.

Comment: Thank you @geetha290krm. We still have to show that $G$ is an extension of $g$, that is $G|_Y=g|_Y$.

Comment: It is an extension because $G(x)=\lim G_n(x)=\lim g(x) =g(x)$ for $x \in Y$.

Comment: Thank you, that was quite easy :)

Comment: I guess you assume that the extension has the same norm as the functional we start with.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes.

Comment: Consider $X=\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ and $Y=\mathbb{C}e_1.$ Let $\varphi(ae_1)=a.$ Then $\|\varphi\|=1$ but the set of extensions is not compact as it consists of all sequences $x\in \ell^\infty$ such that $\|x\|_\infty=1$ and $x_1=1.$ Indeed, if it was compact the unit ball in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N}\setminus \{1\})$ would be compact.

Comment: Let $\varphi(y_0)=1.$ Then the set of all extensions is contained in $\{\psi\in X'\,:\,\psi (y_0)=1\}$ The latter is a closed affine subspace of $X'.$ Hence its interior is empty.

Comment: You can never have an open disk in a normed linear space such that every element of the disk has the same norm.

Comment: @geetha290krm The interior is empty even if we consider all extensions with no requirement that the norm is preserved